# need help for html popover like a tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Click on the below text to view the website template

[In this website when you hover on any product it shows the product description exactly on the product with images and texts. Can someone help me how can I achieve this with bootstrap tooltip or any other easy way or in other words I have created the same popped up div with same style how to show it on product when I hover over it with help of Jquery or javascript.](https://www.gambio-shop.de/shop1/index.php)

Comment: can you post what you have try so far..code?

Comment: Do you mean use of `title` attribute?

Comment: no not title but want something like when I hover on a specific product a div with display:none should exactly displayed on that specific product

Comment: Anuj I am trying something new so will tell you what I have done tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You get the hovered object position and then you just move popup over that hovered object, fairly simple?

```
$('item').hover(function(){
    $('popup').fadeIn();
    $('popup').offset({top: ..., left:...})
})
```

Something like that.

Comment: got the idea. Will tell you the results after trying tomorrow, thanks anyway.